# Parse HTML using with an Ant Script

Tags: ant

I need to retrieve some values from an HTML file. I need to use Ant so I can use these values in other parts of my script.

Can this even be achieved in Ant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the other answers you can't do this in "pure" XML. You need to embed a programming language. My personal favourite is Groovy,  it's [integration with ANT](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) is excellent.

Here's a sample which retrieves the logo URL, from the groovy homepage:

```
parse:

print:
     [echo] 
     [echo]         Logo URL: http://groovy.codehaus.org/images/groovy-logo-medium.png
     [echo]
```

### build.xml

Build uses the [ivy plug-in](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) to retrieve all 3rd party dependencies.

```
<project name="demo" default="print" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="resolve">
        <ivy:resolve/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="parse" depends="resolve">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <groovy>
        import org.htmlcleaner.*

        def address = 'http://groovy.codehaus.org/'

        // Clean any messy HTML
        def cleaner = new HtmlCleaner()
        def node = cleaner.clean(address.toURL())

        // Convert from HTML to XML
        def props = cleaner.getProperties()
        def serializer = new SimpleXmlSerializer(props)
        def xml = serializer.getXmlAsString(node)

        // Parse the XML into a document we can work with
        def page = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(xml)

        // Retrieve the logo URL
        properties["logo"] = page.body.div[0].div[1].div[0].div[0].div[0].img.@src
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="print" depends="parse">
        <echo>
        Logo URL: ${logo}
        </echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

The parsing logic is pure groovy programming. I love the way you can easily walk the page's DOM tree:

```
// Retrieve the logo URL
properties["logo"] = page.body.div[0].div[1].div[0].div[0].div[0].img.@src
```

### ivy.xml

[Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is similar to Maven. It manages your dependencies on 3rd party software. Here it's being used to pull down groovy and the HTMLCleaner library the groovy logic is using:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="build->default">
        <conf name="build" description="ANT tasks"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.codehaus.groovy" name="groovy-all" rev="1.8.2"/>
        <dependency org="net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner" name="htmlcleaner" rev="2.2"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

### How to install ivy

[Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is a standard ANT plugin. Download it's jar and place it in one of the following directories:

```
$HOME/.ant/lib
$ANT_HOME/lib
```

I don't know why the ANT project doesn't ship with ivy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is very possible.

Note that in order to use this solution you will need to set your JAVA_HOME variable to JRE 1.6 or later.

```
<project name="extractElement" default="test">
<!--Extract element from html file-->
<scriptdef name="findelement" language="javascript">
     <attribute name="tag" />
     <attribute name="file" />
     <attribute name="property" />
     <![CDATA[
       var tag = attributes.get("tag");
       var file = attributes.get("file");
       var regex = "<" + tag + "[^>]*>(.*?)</" + tag + ">";
       var patt = new RegExp(regex,"g");
       project.setProperty(attributes.get("property"), patt.exec(file));
     ]]>
</scriptdef>

<!--Only available target...-->
<target name="test">
    <!--Load html file into property-->
    <loadfile srcFile="D:\Tools\CruiseControl\Build\artifacts\RECO\20110831100942\RECO_merged_report.html" property="html.file"/>
    <!--Find element with specific tag and save it to property element-->
    <findelement tag="title" file="${html.file}" property="element"/>
    <echo message="File : ${html.file}"/>
    <echo message="Title : ${element}"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Output : `[echo] Title : <title>Test Report</title>,Test Report`

As I don't know what exactly variables you were looking for this particular solution will find all elements that you specify in the tag attribute. Of course you could modify the regex to suit your own specific needs.

Also this is pure build.xml ant with no external dependencies whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you have to write your own task for it. Visit http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#writingowntask for more information about writing own tasks for Ant. In your Ant task you may parse your HTML file as needed.

I claim, that it is not directly possible with "pure" XML (build.xml) to achieve what you want.

Comment: Why wouldn't the [<XmlProperty>](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) task work? After all, HTML is just a subset of XML.

Comment: HTML is not a subset of XML. If you talk about XHTML, it's an application of XML. The <XmlProperty> will work, if the input document is really written as a XML document. But the syntax of "classic" HTML is more liberally than the syntax of XHTML ...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) task and see if it'll work for you. It's pretty straight forward:

```
<xmlProperty file="${html.file}"
   prefix="html."/>
```

After all, HTML is just a subset of XML. I've used it before to do this very task. No need to write your own task or script.

Comment: I'd agree that this simple solution might work, provided the page is well formed. Problem is HTML is not a subset of XML. Many pages need to be first "cleaned" or converted.

Comment: Well, if it works, it'll save Decrypter a lot of headaches. Officially, HTML was always a subset of XML, but web browsers allowed people to get away with loosey-goosey syntax. Oh Netscape, I have sinned before thee by not ending a table data with a `</td>` before staring the next table row with a `<tr>`. Absolved! The worst was `<p>` which people began to assume meant you were ending a paragraph instead of starting one. Fortunately, most of the newer webpages are better syntactically, and are true XHTML. It's worth a try.

Comment: It's a pity the W3C didn't just mandate XHTML, like you stated it would have been a formalisation of what HTML should have been from day one, a superset of XML. In practice I've found it's necessary to jump thru hoops and "decrypt" HTML pages.... All it takes is one deviation and the XML parser will reject the page :-(