# Is it possible to launch Gradle tasks from Ant?

Tags: ant, build-automation, gradle

I am researching replacements for Ant.  I've looked at [Gant](http://gant.codehaus.org/) and [Gradle](http://gradle.org/).

Is it possible to kick off a Gradle task from Ant?  This is possible in Gant with a taskdef.

```xml
<taskdef
    name         = "gant"
    classname    = "org.codehaus.gant.ant.Gant"
    classpathref = "classpath" 
    />

<gant />
```

Is there something similar Gradle?  I'm eager to start migrating from Ant to Gradle, but we have a large Ant infrastructure and any Gradle build scripts I create need to be callable from Ant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't offer an Ant task to run a Gradle build from Ant. What you could do is to invoke a Gradle command (like `gradle build`) from Ant.

In terms of Ant integration, Gradle offers two features: Importing Ant builds, and reusing Ant tasks.

Gradle is very different from Gant. Gradle is an entire new build system; Gant is a thin layer above Ant.

Comment: That's too bad, but thank you for the info.  Gant would be perfect, but it doesn't allow for dynamic task/target creation (gantfile format precludes it).  So I turned to Gradle, which has many more features than I need, but does support dynamic tasks, but not being called from Ant.  Oh well. :)

Answer (score 8):

Create a macrodef for gradle, call it just like any other task.  Here is the setup and an example...

```
    <!-- Gradle path stuff -->
<property environment="env" />
<condition property="gradle.executable" value="${env.GRADLE_HOME}/bin/gradle.bat" else="${env.GRADLE_HOME}/bin/gradle">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<!-- Macro def, gives us an ant 'gradle' task-->
<macrodef name="gradle">
    <attribute name="task" />
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="${gradle.executable}" dir="." failonerror="true">
            <arg value="@{task}" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Example of using the macro def

```
<!-- Example, call grade with new macro -->
<target name="example">
    <gradle task="build" />
</target>
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass all the command line properties received by ant to pass to gradle macrodef ?

Comment: Project properties passed through command line (using -P<propname> = propvalue). I am looking for way to collect all command line project properties while ant is invoked, and pass them to the gradle calls that happen through macrodef.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of switching build technology, why not use a combination of [ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) and [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) to extend the capabilities of your existing ant builds?

An example is the following posting:

[Parse HTML using with an Ant Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script/7435804#7435804)

BTW I'm a big fan of Gradle, however, like you I have to live with and support a large ANT legacy :-)

Comment: +1...  too many people to live with and support a large ANT legacy. Extending via scripting provides middle path..

Answer (score 3):

Actually I want to do the same thing and where implemented by calling a sh file and then the sh was calling the gradle but it was too much around the bush and finally the following code made it to work cool..

Hope this will help you..

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="gradle.wrapper.executable" location="${env.GRADLE_HOME}/bin/gradle" />
<target name="dependencies-report" description="Creates a text file report of the depdency tree">
<exec executable="${gradle.wrapper.executable}" dir=".">
    <arg value="dependencyReport" />
</exec>
</target>
```