# Is there a way in Ant (using Groovy?) to post info to an http URL and then parse the response?

Tags: parsing, post, ant, groovy, htmlcleaner

I've found a way to read an HTML page in Ant with Groovy + HTMLCleaner (see: [Parse HTML using with an Ant Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script) ) but I am unable to find a way to first POST some data to a URL and then get a response and be able to parse that with HTMLCleaner (or something similar). Is this posible?

Comment: Using ant's exec task you can use cURL for POSTS.  See http://superuser.com/questions/149329/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-the-curl-command-line-tool

Comment: But then how do I parse the response? I'd especially like it to be as clean as HTMLCleaner which enables traversing the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the groovy [REST client](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html), which is part of the HTTPBuilder project.

```
<target name="invoke-webservice">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <groovy>
        import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
        import groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult
        import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.URLENC

        def twitter = new RESTClient( 'https://twitter.com/statuses/' )

        def resp = twitter.post( path : 'update.xml',
                 body : [ status:msg, source:'httpbuilder' ],
                 requestContentType : URLENC )

        log.info "response status: ${resp.status}"
    </groovy>
</target>
```