# How to create a gitlab project from terminal or command line

Tags: git, bash, shell, ant, gitlab

I have internal setup gitlab server. I want to run separate ant script and create a project in that gitlab server. (without creating new project in gitlab UI)

In the ant i can use exec executable and run the bash commands.

And also how to send the Visibility Level and other parameters to gitlab server to create the project?

Answer (score 5):

You Would need to use the GitLab API to **[create a project](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/projects.md#create-project)**

```
POST /projects
```

One of the optional parameters is:

`visibility_level` (optional):

> - 0 is Private (Project access must be granted explicitly for each user)

- 10 is Internal (The project can be cloned by any logged in user),
- 20 is Public (The project can be cloned without any authentication)

Using a [private token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29065698/6309) (and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)):

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: QVy1PB7sTxfy4pqfZM1U" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-X POST \
--data-urlencode 'name=myproject' \
--data-urlencode 'visibility_level=0' \
"http://example.com/api/v3/projects"
```

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708626/is-there-a-way-in-ant-using-groovy-to-post-info-to-an-http-url-and-then-parse/9727828#9727828

Comment: in case someone reaches here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project

Comment: Where is `jq` used in this example?

Comment: @JFabianMeier in the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/29065698/6309 mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To create a gitlab project from terminal or command line using HTTPS, these are the commands:

```
//In a desired local folder
git init
//Add all files to commit
git add -A
//Commit all
git commit -m "Inital version"
//Add an alias origin to master branch
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/minhasaulas/2018/corporativos/ServidorEureka.git
//Push change to remote repository
git push origin master
```

If you want to create a gitlab project from terminal or command line using SSH visit this url:
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-git-and-github-on-windows

Comment: if I see it correctly this doesnt create a new project, but setup a local system to work with an existing project. For this you would still have to navigate to the webinterface and click "create new project". But still helpful though

Answer (score 2):

@eli you are right! The last one is to an existing repository. The code below it to create a repository from terminal only:

```
    //In a desired local folder
    git init

    //Add all files to commit
    git add .

    //Commit all
    git commit -m "Inital version"

    //Push data to remote repository and to master branch
    git push --set-upstream https://gitlab.com/your_repository_name_go_here.git master
```