# @Grab annotation fails under Ant

Tags: ant, groovy, ivy

I'm using a @Grab annotation to grab the definition of an Html parser I can give to the XMLSlurper (I think it's the tagsoup parser) and all is good when I run my script from the cmd line. If I invoke the same script from Ant I get an Ivy NoClassDefFound error. I think it may berelated to having Ivy in Antlib. Is there another way to parse Html without customizing the slurper via @Grab?

This:

```
@Grab(group='org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module='tagsoup', version='1.2' )
doc = new XmlSlurper(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()).parse(confluenceWebPageInputStream)
```

Works just fine from the command line but when I run it from an Ant build target:

```
<target name="update-wiki-chart">
    <echo message="Will update chart for version ${version}"/>
    <java dir="${basedir}" classname="groovy.lang.GroovyShell">
        <arg value="ParseWikiPage.groovy"/>
        <classpath refid="groovylib"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

where groovyLib is a path ref pointing to the Groovy-1.8.6 jar downloaded from our internal Nexus repo, I get the NoClassDefFound error. I'm thinking this is probably due to having Ivy installed in Antlib causing the class loader to find it in two places. I just thought of something while writing this post. I can probably run java in forked mode or do something to cause it to not see/share Ant's classpath.It's been a few years since I've wrestled w/ Ant and class loader issues. My project is a little delinquent due to the bug and I'm looking for a quick/easy fix.

I just tried running my groovy on the cmd line via the "java" cmd and loading groovy-all jar in the class path and I realized that I get the NoClassDefFound error there as well. It has nothing to do with collisions with Ivy under Antlib. Rather, I am missing Ivy altogether. I had assumed it was included in Groovy-all.jar. I just need a clever way of passing Ivy from AntLib into my java task to get this all up and running.

Comment: Could you supply some more details? (an example would be helpful) How are you running the groovy script? ANT exec task or the ANT groovy task? Is the script embedded within the ANT script or an external file? Apologies there are lots of possible variations.

Comment: Apologies for being so terse. I pounded my question out on an Android web browser on a crowded train on my way home. I'll add a little more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing one or more jars from the classpath. I'd suggest digging around the classpathref you've labelled "groovylib".

A less error prone way to launch groovy from within ANT using the [groovy ANT task](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task).

Here's a similar example to your use-case:

[Parse HTML using with an Ant Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script/7435804#7435804)

My example uses ivy directly to manage all build dependencies. The Grab annotations are still supported but obviously these would only manage the dependencies of the groovy script.

Comment: Thanks, I found my mistake. I had been assuming the groovy-all.jar shipped with Ivy which it doesn't. I merely needed to add ivy to the class path to get the grab annotations working.

Comment: @Cliff Perfect. Yes, groovy-all is a special distribution of groovy that packages everything into a single jar.