# How to extract an attribute from an HTML element with Ant?

Tags: html, ant

I have an ANT configuration file which is becoming complicated, and now I'm stuck with an issue. One of the tasks retrieves a page from a website and saves it to a file. I need to load such file and extract from it the *href* attribute of a specific element. HTML is reasonably well formed, but I can't guarantee it.

I was thinking of a RegEx, but the element's attributes are not guaranteed to always appear in the same order (e.g. its class name, or id). Besides, I haven't found out how to just return the **value** of the *href* attribute, without the attribute itself.

I'm trying to limit the amount of addons to be added to ANT, therefore a "self-contained" solution would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse HTML using with an Ant Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're going to find the specific HTML element that has the href you're looking for (I'd assume by checking an id attribute, but you did not say so). I put together this chain of regex's to filter the HTML down to candidate anchor tags and then ultimately strip out just the href's.  I used the source of this page as my sample input and since I couldn't find any id attributes associated to anchors (that also had hrefs), I filtered down to anchors with the class="question-hyperlink" -- I'm hopeful this could be a good starting point for you (and note: as you stipulated, it does not contain any dependencies on additional modules, etc, regardless of how easy they are to install):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Test Html attribute" default="test" basedir=".">
   <target name="test">

      <loadfile srcFile="ant.htm" property="html">
         <filterchain>
            <linecontainsregexp>
              <regexp pattern="&lt;a.*href[^&gt;]*&gt;"/>
              <regexp pattern="&lt;a.*class=[&quot;']question-hyperlink[&quot;'][^&gt;]*&gt;"/>
            </linecontainsregexp>
            <tokenfilter>
               <replaceregex pattern=".*&lt;a.*href=[&quot;']?([^&gt;&quot;']*).*&gt;[^&lt;]*" replace="\1" flags="gi"/>
            </tokenfilter>
         </filterchain>
      </loadfile>

      <echo>${html}</echo>
   </target>
</project>
```