# Extract number from html page using ant and regex

Tags: regex, ant

I have to extract number from web page using ant. I have downloaded page using  task.
Ma page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Index of .......</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
<H1>Index of .....</H1>
<PRE><IMG SRC="/icons/blank.gif" ALT="     "> <A HREF="?N=A">Name</A>                    <A HREF="?M=D">Last modified</A>       <A HREF="?S=A">Size</A>  <A HREF="?D=A">Description</A>
<HR>
<IMG SRC="/icons/back.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="/projects/i/">Parent Directory</A>            19-Dec-2012 11:39       -  
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120114-1731/">20120114-1731/</A>          14-Feb-2012 17:40       -  
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120115-1055/">20120115-1055/</A>          15-Feb-2012 11:04       -  
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120115-1336/">20120115-1336/</A>          15-Feb-2012 13:44       -  
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120115-1656/">20120115-1656/</A>          15-Feb-2012 17:05       -  
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120115-2157/">20120115-2157/</A>          15-Feb-2012 22:06       -  
</PRE><HR>
<ADDRESS>Apache/1.3.41 Server at romgsa.ibm.com Port 443</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

From:
<IMG SRC="/icons/folder.gif" ALT="[DIR]"> <A HREF="20120114-1731/"&
gt;20120114-1731/</A>  I
I have to extract "20120114-1731"

Comment: You're best advised to use a HTML parser. Similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428855/parse-html-using-with-an-ant-script/7435804#7435804

Comment: I have to use only Ant core targets :(

Comment: My example uses ivy to download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The following example embeds a [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) script. Groovy has a useful Grab annotation which can be used to download Java libraries like [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/), which enables a HTML page to be parsed as XML.

## Example

The bootstrap target will download and install groovy.

```
$ ant bootstrap
```

Running the build produces the following expected output:

```
$ ant
..
parse:
   [groovy] 20120114-1731/
   [groovy] 20120115-1055/
   [groovy] 20120115-1336/
   [groovy] 20120115-1656/
   [groovy] 20120115-2157/
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="parse">

    <target name="bootstrap">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.1/groovy-all-2.1.1.jar"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="parse"> 
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

        <groovy>
            import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
            import org.htmlcleaner.SimpleXmlSerializer;

            @Grab(group='net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner', module='htmlcleaner', version='2.2.1')

            // HTML page to parse
            def address = 'file:///path/to/example/page.html'

            // Clean any messy HTML
            def cleaner = new HtmlCleaner()
            def node = cleaner.clean(address.toURL())

            // Convert from HTML to XML
            def serializer = new SimpleXmlSerializer(cleaner.getProperties())
            def xml = serializer.getXmlAsString(node)

            // Parse the XML into a document we can work with
            def page = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText(xml)

            // Retrieve the anchor tag values matching a pattern
            def numbers = page.body.pre.a.findAll { it.toString().startsWith("2012") }
            numbers.each {
                println it
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

</project>
```